# Links are not showing as buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, actionview

In my app/views/users/sessions/new.html.slim, I have:

```
.container
  = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: {class: "form-signin"}) do |f|
    h2.form-signin-heading
      = t('users.mailer.registrations.sessions.new.please_sign_in')
    .form-group
      .sr-only
        = f.label t('users.sessions.new.email_address')
      = f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control form-signin email_input', autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email Address", required: ""
      .sr-only
        = f.label t('users.sessions.new.password')
      = f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control form-signin password_input', autofocus: true, placeholder: "Password", required: ""
    - if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      .center-checkbox
        .form-check
          label.form-check-label
            = f.check_box :remember_me
            = t('users.sessions.new.remember_me')
    .form-group
      = f.submit t('users.mailer.sessions.new.log_in'), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
    = render "devise/shared/links"
```

In my app/views/users/shares/_links.html.sim, I have:

```
- if controller_name != 'sessions'
  .form-group
    = link_to t('users.shared._links.log_in'), new_session_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
    br
- if devise_mapping.registerable? && controller_name != 'registrations'
  .form-group
    = link_to t('users.shared._links.sign_up'), new_registration_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
    br
- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations'
  .form-group
    = link_to t('users.shared._links.forgot_password'), new_password_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
    br
- if devise_mapping.confirmable? && controller_name != 'confirmations'
  .form-group
    = link_to t('users.shared._links.no_confirmation_instructions'), new_confirmation_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
    br
- if devise_mapping.lockable? && resource_class.unlock_strategy_enabled?(:email) && controller_name != 'unlocks'
  .form-group
    = link_to t('users.shared._links.no_unlock_instructions'), new_unlock_path(resource_name), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
    br
- if devise_mapping.omniauthable?
  .form-group
    - resource_class.omniauth_providers.each do |provider|
      = link_to "#{t('users.shared._links.sign_in_with')} #{OmniAuth::Utils.camelize(provider)}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider), class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"
      br
```

In my assets/stylesheets/signin.css.scss, (I import it into applicatio.css.scss), I have:

```
.form-signin {
  max-width: 330px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form-signin body {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  background-color: #ee
}
.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin .center-checkbox {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-signin .form-control {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.form-signin .form-control:focus {
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-signin .email_input {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.form-signin .password_input {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
```

Instead of buttons, for the shared links, here's what I'm getting:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Next step is to inspect the Sign up button in the browser. Are the classes being applied properly?

Comment: No, the classes are not properly applied, which is the problem I'm dealing with

Answer (score 0):

`link_to` generates a `<a>` tag, which is not `button type="button"`. What you should use should be a `button_to` for example-

```
= button_to t('users.shared._links.log_in'), new_session_path(resource_name),:class => "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block", :method => :get
```

All you have to do is add a `:method => "get"`, you can get your method type from routes, to the end of your `button_to` to get it to be treated like a link

thank you.

Comment: No,button_to is generating an <a> tag as well, and you don't need to specify a method, when you have something like new_session_path(resource_name), per the action_view button_to docs